# filter() arguments not giving correct output

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

My problem today could be rather simple.  I am trying to obtain all required elements inside of a form for which there is no text (they are of type input, text).  Here is my JS:

```
var inputs = $('#form').find(':input');
if(inputs.filter('[required] [value=""]').first().focus().length)
//do something
```

This is the element in the HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="title[]" id="name_" required />
```

I should add that this input element is being added dynamically by javascript, meaning, it's appended after a certain action has taken place.

The true problem is that the code inside of the if statement is never true even when I don't type a value for the given text field.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `[required][value=""]` insn't the same as `[required] [value=""]` or did you mean `[required], [value=""]`?

Comment: There is a difference with and without the space? You have to be kidding me lol. It's the one without the space that's not working

Comment: Could you add where the `required` is in the html

Comment: Well, spaces have meaning in selectors, same as in CSS. With a space you are selecting children of required inputs, that have no value. Without space you're selecting required inputs with no value. With a comma you select required AND empty value inputs.

Comment: `[required] [value=""]` will select elements with `value=""` that are children of another element that has the `required` attribute, like `<div required><input value=""></div>`, is that what you want?

Comment: Btw, browsers do take care of `required` input fields themselves with appropriate UI. You don't have to manually focus it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `value` attribute of an input tag is not the same thing as the `value` property of an input element. The first one happens to be in the HTML, gets parsed in the DOM and acts as the `defaultValue`. The latter one is the dynamic value which represents the currently entered input. See also [.prop() vs .attr()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5874652/1048572)

Your element does not even *have* a `value` attribute, so it will never match the selector. Instead, you will need to use a filter function that checks the properties:

```
inputs.filter(function() {
     return this.required && this.value=="";
     // equivalent: $(this).prop("required")
     // and         $(this).prop("value") or $(this).val()
})
```

Comment: This makes a lot of sense and it will probably be what I go with. However, I was running this in a separate project and it was working fine, the problem occurred when exporting it to a separate project. Do you have any idea of why or how it was working?

Comment: Maybe you had an `<input required value="">` somewhere, but I'd then expect it to always match the selector. Unless you were calling something like `.attr("value", "…")` on it.

Answer (score 3):

If you mean to select required inputs that are empty, your selector is wrong. The space represents ancestor relationship, parent/children:

```
if (inputs.filter('[required][value=""]').length) { // Element is `required` and empty
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are **2 issues** with your code.

```
('[required] [value=""]')
```

Supposed to be

```
('[required][value=""]')
```

And with the above selector you can never select the input below

```
<input type="text" name="title[]" id="name_" />
```

as it has **no value attribute** in the first place. Also required **attribute is missing**

The inputs that would match your selector would be of this signature

```
<input type="text" required="true" value="" name="title[]" id="name_" />
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AnxTb/1/)**

Comment: He's trying to use filter to check the value after somebody has typed something in it.  The method he is attempting is wrong, [value=""] won't work if somebody actually typed something in the input.  @Bergi is correct with his answer.